# Mounting Bernoulli 230 Disk

Tags: mount, xubuntu, scsi

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 and have connected an Iomega Bernoulli 230A drive to the system via SCSI.

Running 'lsscsi' shows the drive is listed by scsi controller and seen by the OS. Unfortunately, I've tried a couple of different disks and they will not mount. The system keeps complaining that it cannot find valid superblocks.

I'm unsure how I can mount disks in this device. Has anyone had previous experience mounting disks from this type of drive?

Comment: Does it create a device like `/dev/sdXN`? if so, what does `sudo file -sL /dev/sdXN` say?

Comment: Yes. Output of 'lsscsi' shows it is /dev/sde. If I run the file command you mentioned the output just replies  'empty'